# Get the Index of the Node in a Primefaces Tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

I am using a Primefaces Tree which has a following structure :

Node 1

Node 1.1

Node 1.2

Node 1.3

Now, I want to add a node in between Node 1.1 and Node 1.2. I can do that by using "add(int index, TreeNode element)" method. But for that I must know the index of Node 1.1.

Is there any way to get the index of a Node by it's name or by any other means?

Comment: It's by recursion, and it can get pretty expensive, depending on your data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another example which present a easy way to add now node below specific node.

XHTML

```
<h:form>
    <p:tree value="#{treeBasicView.root}" 
            id="tree"
            var="node" 
            dynamic="true">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>

    <p:outputLabel value="add node : " />
    <p:inputText id="newNodeName" 
                 value="#{treeBasicView.newNodeName}"/>

    <p:outputLabel value="below : " />
    <p:inputText id="selectedNodeName" 
                 value="#{treeBasicView.selectedNodeName}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="add child" 
                     process="@this,newNodeName,selectedNodeName"
                     update="tree"
                     actionListener="#{treeBasicView.addNewNode}"/>
</h:form>
```

ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="treeBasicView")
@ViewScoped
public class BasicView implements Serializable {

    private TreeNode root;
    private TreeNode selectedNode;
    private int position;
    private String selectedNodeName;
    private String newNodeName;

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public String getSelectedNodeName() {
        return selectedNodeName;
    }

    public void setSelectedNodeName(String selectedNodeName) {
        this.selectedNodeName = selectedNodeName;
    }

    public String getNewNodeName() {
        return newNodeName;
    }

    public void setNewNodeName(String newNodeName) {
        this.newNodeName = newNodeName;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);

        TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);
        TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);

        TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);

        node1.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1"));
        node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0"));
        node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1"));
        node01.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0"));
        node10.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0"));
        root.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2"));
    }

    public void addNewNode(ActionEvent event) {
        findNode(root);
        selectedNode.getParent().getChildren().add(position, new DefaultTreeNode(newNodeName));
    }

    private void findNode(TreeNode node){
        int pos = 0;
        List<TreeNode> subChild = node.getChildren();
        for (TreeNode treeNode : subChild) {
            pos = pos + 1;
            if(treeNode.getData().equals(selectedNodeName)){
                position = pos;
                selectedNode = treeNode;
            }
            findNode(treeNode);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Figure 1]

After click add child

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 2):

This is my example which present a easy way to add now node inside specific node.

XHTML

```
<h:form>
    <p:tree value="#{treeBasicView.root}" 
            id="tree"
            var="node" 
            dynamic="true">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>

    <p:outputLabel value="add node : " />
    <p:inputText id="newNodeName" 
                 value="#{treeBasicView.newNodeName}"/>

    <p:outputLabel value="to into : " />
    <p:inputText id="selectedNodeName" 
                 value="#{treeBasicView.selectedNodeName}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="add child" 
                     process="@this,newNodeName,selectedNodeName"
                     update="tree"
                     actionListener="#{treeBasicView.addNewNode}"/>
</h:form>
```

ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "treeBasicView")
@ViewScoped
public class BasicView implements Serializable {

    private TreeNode root;
    private String selectedNodeName;
    private String newNodeName;

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public String getSelectedNodeName() {
        return selectedNodeName;
    }

    public void setSelectedNodeName(String selectedNodeName) {
        this.selectedNodeName = selectedNodeName;
    }

    public String getNewNodeName() {
        return newNodeName;
    }

    public void setNewNodeName(String newNodeName) {
        this.newNodeName = newNodeName;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);

        TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);
        TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);

        TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);

        node1.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1"));
        node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0"));
        node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1"));
        node01.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0"));
        node10.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0"));
        root.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2"));
    }

    public void addNewNode(ActionEvent event) {
        findNode(root);
    }
    
    private void findNode(TreeNode node){
        List<TreeNode> subChild = node.getChildren();
        for (TreeNode treeNode : subChild) {
            if(treeNode.getData().equals(selectedNodeName)){
                treeNode.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode(newNodeName));
                break;
            }
            findNode(treeNode);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Figure 1]

After click add child
[image: Figure 3]

You can apply with this example by using `treeNode.getChildren().add(i, name)` and so on.