# Primefaces tree create new node inside other node

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to create a new node inside [tree](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/basic.xhtml) dynamically.

```
<p:tree value="#{treeBasicView.root}" var="node" dynamic="true">
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

If it possible, how to do it. Kindly help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do.

You should see examples from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252529/get-the-index-of-the-node-in-a-primefaces-tree).
In the example, Recursion is used for demonstration.