# Primefaces Tree: don't remove the node after drag and drop

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, drag-and-drop, tree

Is it possible not to remove the node from the original PrimeFacesTree after dragging it? The default behaviour is that a node that was dragged and dropped in another place is removed. Can i prevent that from happening?

I'm using Primefaces 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any premade attribute to duplicate node on dropEvent.

The solution is to add a listener to your `<p:tree>` element :

```
<p:tree listener="#{managingBean.onDragDrop}" />
```

Then you need to re-create node on initial location by duplicating it in your backbean method :

```
public void onDragDrop(TreeDragDropEvent event) {
    TreeNode dragNode = event.getDragNode();
    TreeNode dropNode = event.getDropNode();
    int dropIndex = event.getDropIndex();

    // Logic to repopulate initial Tree element
}
```

And don't forget to re-draw your tree

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! if i undestand this correctly event.getDropIndex() would give me the index of the place where the node was dropped. How can i find out where the node came from?

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately, there isn't any method to get initial index. See documentation : http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/event/TreeDragDropEvent.html. You can see this solution to find index of a node in a tree : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252529/get-the-index-of-the-node-in-a-primefaces-tree

Comment: I would like to achieve the same task... no way to solve this issue? Override a method,...?

Comment: The response of Thrax seems a bit weird, can't find any "listener" property on the "p:tree" official documentation (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/dragdrop.xhtml) Maybe he mean the code `<p:ajax event="dragdrop" listener="#{treeDNDView.onDragDrop}" .../>` instead.